# New LED light fitting flickering

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture, led

Recently moved into a new home and replaced the main light fitting in the sitting room. We replaced it with this dimmable LED fitting:

https://www.leycroftlighting.co.uk/endon-rubens-6lt-semi-flush-79469?gclid=Cj0KCQjw4v2EBhCtARIsACan3nxJ0tKAQnqt4noe7I0xnm7tTwk-Xl6RuXjAd3FiHT_1iqSWbqgXiO0aAoYuEALw_wcB

> Specification
> Lampholder
> E27
> Lamp Type
> FILAMENT
> Max Wattage
> 40
> Number Of Light Sources
> 6
> Voltage
> 230

After wiring it up, the fitting worked but the lights flickered constantly. I read this was likely due to the dimmer switch itself not being compatible with an LED, so I replaced the switch with one of these:

https://www.screwfix.com/p/lap-1-gang-2-way-led-dimmer-switch-white/273cc

[image]

[image]

It's still flickering.

What switch or accessories do I need to get stable lighting?

Comment: sounds like it needs better bulbs. Many cheap filament-looking bulbs are just a series of 30 or 70 LEDs, which means they are only lit about 1/4th the time. Sometimes they put 2 of these LED strings back to back, so they are lit closer to half the time, but it's still flicker city. See if a regular (cheap) LED bulbs flickers; if not, you know it's the bulb's fault.

Comment: @dandavis thanks. I did put cheap bulbs in, as they seemed to vary in price so much. Sadly I don't have a single other LED bulb that would fit to test it right now. We put these in - don't imagine you can tell from the description if they're likely the source of the problem? https://www.screwfix.com/p/lap-es-st64-led-light-bulb-470lm-6w/963fh